# "TypeError: unsupported operand types" only when using certain filter

Tags: django

When I use the filter of `filter(user=user, product=product)` it shows the error of `unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'` However, when I only use `filter(product=product)` it does not show any error. Any solutions?

Here is the code snippet that I use in `views.py`

```
for product in Product.objects.all():
    product_total_value = Transaction.objects.filter(user=user,
        product=product).aggregate(Sum('value'))
    total = Transaction.objects.aggregate(Sum('value'))
    percentage = product_total_value['value__sum'] / total['value__sum'] * 100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of either **`product_total_value['value__sum']`** or **`total['value__sum']`** has **`None`** value.
So, you have to handle those cases as below,

```
for product in Product.objects.all():
    product_total_value = Transaction.objects.filter(user=user, product=product).aggregate(Sum('value'))
    total = Transaction.objects.aggregate(Sum('value'))

    if product_total_value['value__sum'] and total['value__sum']:
        percentage = product_total_value['value__sum'] / total['value__sum'] * 100
    else:
        percentage = 0
```

Comment: I see. So you mean it's because one of the users does not have any transactions with a product and it returns None?